# Position ScrollView below LinearLayout inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I'm creating a scrollable menu (ScrollView) with a close button (LinearLayout) that stays at the top of the screen.

My full screen is a RelativeLayout - that Has a LinearLayout (close button) and then a ScrollView (menu) inside it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/DashboardView_Root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/DashboardView_menuHeaderContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/DashboardView_barContainer"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/DashboardView_barContainer"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/DashboardView_menuBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/layoutPaddingLess"
            android:contentDescription="Menu"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_vertical" />
        <Iag.TextView
            android:id="@+id/DashboardView_menuHeading"
            style="@style/Text.H3.Light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layoutPadding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Scrollview
    android:id="@+id/DashboardView_menuContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:fillViewport="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

All looks perfect except that the Scrollview goes up too high, underneath the close button. I want the ScrollView menu to stop at the bottom of the close button (frameLayout).

[image]

How do I stop the menu from starting in the same place as the close button (the top of the screen)?

**EDIT: Sorry, I said the close button was a FrameLayout Initially but it is a LinearLayout. See code axml above.**

Here is the full code for the whole page - the menu just pops out over top the rest of the screen if the user clicks the menu icon:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/DashboardView_Root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/DashboardView_contentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/DashboardView_downBtn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/DashboardView_barContainer" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/DashboardView_downBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/layoutPadding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/DashboardView_barContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/DashboardView_upBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ab_logo"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/layoutPaddingLess"
            android:contentDescription="Up"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/DashboardView_helpBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ab_help"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/layoutPaddingLess"
            android:contentDescription="Help"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/DashboardView_menuHeaderContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/DashboardView_barContainer"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/DashboardView_barContainer"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/DashboardView_menuBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/layoutPaddingLess"
            android:contentDescription="Menu"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_vertical" />
        <Iag.TextView
            android:id="@+id/DashboardView_menuHeading"
            style="@style/Text.H3.Light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layoutPadding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Scrollview
    android:id="@+id/DashboardView_menuContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:fillViewport="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `android:layout_below`?

Comment: @TheAnonymous010 That works! Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Will you accept my post as the answer to help other people solve this issue?

Comment: Nevermind, I see that you already did :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in your case, use `android:layout_below` to position it below your button. In relative layouts, this kind of attribute is always available.